# How Do I Create A New Ethereum Account/Address In My DApp

Tags: web3js, truffle, hd-wallets

i am starting to learn how to create a Dapp and i am trying to create a way for users to login without having to use metamask.

I am using `truffle-hdwallet-provider` which works fine for creating an account but i don't think i understand how it works.

I can create a new instance of a provider using:

```
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, network);
```

It will create an address no matter what string value i use for `mnemonic`. if a wallet can be created with any string value, then why does metamask enforce a 12 word mnemonic?

If an account can be created with a mnemonic, why does metamask ask for the `private key` if i want to import an account?

What is the functional difference between the mnemonic and the private key if both can get the same address?

Is it possible to use a `private key` to create an account on my app using `HDWalletProvider` i cant find any examples or documentation explaining this.

^^^ I have asked a few questions because i am new to this, any answers to any of the questions is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Mnemonic creates and extended private key (root key), that can create many private keys. https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ 
An extended private key can deterministicly generate millions of private keys, so that you can regenerate all those same addresses in the future as long as you have the extended private key or your mnemonic seed.